# Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint - Basic Migration

Tags: entity-framework-core, entity-framework-core-migrations

I tried to make some project in C# with entity framework core 2.1. However, there is a problem that I can't solve, since I don't see anything wrong. 
I'm trying to just do a simple migrate in my database.
There is no problem until I write 'Update-Database' to Package manager console. After trying to update database, here is the error message:

**Introducing FOREIGN KEY constraint 'FK_Users_Baskets_BasketId' on table 'Users' may cause cycles or multiple cascade paths. Specify ON DELETE NO ACTION or ON UPDATE NO ACTION, or modify other FOREIGN KEY constraints.
Could not create constraint or index. See previous errors.**

**Basket.cs**

```
public class Basket {
            [Key]
            public int BasketId { get; set; }

            public List<ProductByBasket> ProductByBaskets { get; set; }

            public string BasketName { get; set; }
            public int UserId { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("UserId")]
            public User User { get; set; } 
      }
```

**Product.cs**

```
     public class Product {
            [Key]
            public int ProductId { get; set; }

            public List<ProductByBasket> ProductByBaskets { get; set; }

            public string ProductName { get; set; }
      }
```

**ProductByBasket.cs**

```
            [Key]
            public int ProductByBasketId { get; set; }

            public int BasketId { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("BasketId")]
            public Basket Basket { get; set; }

            public int ProductId { get; set; }
            [ForeignKey("ProductId")]
            public Product Product { get; set; }

      }
```

**Migration File**

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
               name: "ProductByBaskets",
               columns: table => new
               {
                   BasketId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                   ProductId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                   ProductByBasketId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false)
               },
               constraints: table =>
               {
                   table.PrimaryKey("PK_ProductByBaskets", x => new { x.ProductId, x.BasketId });
                   table.UniqueConstraint("AK_ProductByBaskets_ProductByBasketId", x => x.ProductByBasketId);
                   table.ForeignKey(
                       name: "FK_ProductByBaskets_Products_ProductId",
                       column: x => x.ProductId,
                       principalTable: "Products",
                       principalColumn: "ProductId",
                       onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
               });
```

**ApplicationDbContext.cs**

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext {
            public ApplicationDbContext() { }

            protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) {
                  string connectionString = @"Data Source=...\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = db; Integrated Security=true;";
                  optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(connectionString);
                  base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
            }

            protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {

                  modelBuilder.Entity<ProductByBasket>()       
       .HasOne(u => u.Basket).WithMany(u => u.ProductByBaskets).IsRequired().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);

                  modelBuilder.Entity<ProductByBasket>()
                     .HasKey(x => new { x.ProductId, x.BasketId });

                  modelBuilder.Entity<ProductByBasket>()
                      .HasOne(pt => pt.Basket)
                      .WithMany(p => p.ProductByBaskets)
                      .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.BasketId); 

                  modelBuilder.Entity<ProductByBasket>()
                      .HasOne(pt => pt.Product)
                      .WithMany(t => t.ProductByBaskets)
                      .HasForeignKey(pt => pt.ProductId);
            }


            public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Basket> Baskets { get; set; } 
            public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; } 
            public DbSet<ProductByBasket> ProductByBaskets { get; set; }

      }
```

I tried to configure migration file to write. Then, it looks like:

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
                name: "ProductByBaskets",
                columns: table => new
                {
                    BasketId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    ProductId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false),
                    ProductByBasketId = table.Column<int>(nullable: false).Annotation("SqlServer:ValueGenerationStrategy", SqlServerValueGenerationStrategy.IdentityColumn)
                },
                constraints: table =>
                {
                      table.PrimaryKey("PK_ProductByBaskets", x => x.ProductByBasketId);
                      table.ForeignKey(
                          name: "FK_ProductByBaskets_Baskets_BasketId",
                          column: x => x.BasketId,
                          principalTable: "Baskets",
                          principalColumn: "BasketId",
                          onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                      table.PrimaryKey("PK_ProductByBaskets", x => new { x.ProductId, x.BasketId });
                    table.UniqueConstraint("AK_ProductByBaskets_ProductByBasketId", x => x.ProductByBasketId);
                    table.ForeignKey(
                        name: "FK_ProductByBaskets_Products_ProductId",
                        column: x => x.ProductId,
                        principalTable: "Products",
                        principalColumn: "ProductId",
                        onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
                });
```

Then I get this error:

**Foreign key references invalid table.**

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Don't try the fix the generated migration, but try to find and fix the code (model or fluent configuration) which is causing the issue. The error message indicates that the problem is in `User` class which you haven't included. Looks like there is a referential cycle - `User.BasketId` <-> `Basket.UserId`

Comment: Thanks it works! :)